# Using lodash to extract the leafs of a mixed object/array

Tags: javascript, lodash

```
var a  = {
  "errors":{
    "meters.electric":[ 
      {"smart_meter":["The smart meter field is required."],"reading":["The selected reading is invalid."]}  
    ],
    "forename":[ 
      {"invalid_character":["Invalid character in forname.", "Blah blah."]}
    ]
  }
};
```

I have a object returns from an API, i need to extract the end values to create a single string. The intended output from above owuld be:

```
The smart meter field is required. The selected reading is invalid.Invalid character in forname. Blah blah.
```

I know i can build a series of loops to achieve this, but is there is a lodash way? Something along the lines of https://lodash.com/docs#flattenDeep ?

Comment: Can you give a broader example? What would you want it to do with other properties in the object? Are you wanting to .toString and concatenate every property in the tree that is a primitive? Or maybe only those that are strings?

Comment: I have added a few more sections to the object and expanded the sentence. Bascially, yes i just want the error strings for the view and just starting with lodash for the first time..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allow me to amuse you with some compositional lodash.

Before you concatenate the strings, you probably want a generic function that can extract the values from object/array of arbitrary complexity. Here's how you might compose this function using existing lodash building blocks:

```
const flattenCol = _.flow(
  _.identity,
  _.partialRight(_.map, _.cond([
    [_.isArray, flattenCol],
    [_.isPlainObject, flattenCol],
    [_.stubTrue, _.identity],
  ])),
  _.flattenDeep
);
```

This will extract all values from your structure, in this case, strings. Let's break this down:

- [flow()](https://lodash.com/docs#flow) is used to compose a larger function, out of [identity()](https://lodash.com/docs#identity), [map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map), and [flattenDeep()](https://lodash.com/docs#flattenDeep).
- [identity()](https://lodash.com/docs#identity) is used to ensure only one argument value is passed to [map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map).
- [partialRight()](https://lodash.com/docs#partialRight) composes a function with the iteratee argument partially-applied to [map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map)
- [cond()](https://lodash.com/docs#cond) composes a function that returns a mapped value based on the conditions passed in. For example, if [isArray()](https://lodash.com/docs#isArray) or [isPlainObject()](https://lodash.com/docs#isPlainObject) returns true, it'll recursively call `flattenCol()`. Otherwise, [stubTrue()](https://lodash.com/docs#stubTrue) is the default, and we simply return the value.
- At this point, we have a nested array structure of values - [flattenDeep()](https://lodash.com/docs#flattenDeep) flattens this to a simple array.

I've found keeping functionality like this generic to be super helpful. To build your string, you can just do:

```
flattenCol(a).join(' ');
```

Or, if you want to keep the compositional party going:

```
const errorString = _.flow(flattenCol, _.partialRight(_.join, ' '));
errorString(a);
```

Comment: This was a great inspiration for me to get to the kind of thing I wanted (and thus got my upvote), but the exact example you gave does not actually work because you're referencing the variable `flattenCol` directly before it was initialized. So it fails for the same reason `const a = a * 2` would. Though I have not tested here, I imagine that using a function that simply calls flattenCol in the place of using it directly (e.g. `(e) => flattenCol(e)`) would probably work.

Answer (score 3):

It's a little ridiculous looking but it works:

```
var flattenStrings = _.flatMap(_.flatMap(a.errors), function (i) { 
    return _.flatMap(i); 
});

_.join(flattenStrings, ' ')
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/wc9y4m3t/1/)

Comment: ha that is sick. i knew there would be something like this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For comparison to lodash, here's an approach using vanilla JavaScript:

```
var a  = {
  "errors":{
    "meters.electric":[ 
      {"smart_meter":["The smart meter field is required."],"reading":["The selected reading is invalid."]}  
    ],
    "forename":[ 
      {"invalid_character":["Invalid character in forname.", "Blah blah."]}
    ]
  }
};

function flattenStrings(obj) {
  if (typeof obj != 'object') {
    return obj.toString();
  }
  return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
    return flattenStrings(obj[key]);
  }).join("");
}

console.log(flattenStrings(a));
```

Note that by treating arrays and plain objects alike and using `Object.keys()`, the indices of the arrays are not guaranteed to be hit in a stable order, so it's possible that running this on the same object on different browsers might order the concatenatation of the strings differently.

You could get around that with a bit of extra code, but it didn't seen important here.

Comment: indeed, however i am trying to get my head into lodash at the moment, it is a small lib when compressed and i am starting to think it will be worth it in the long run

Comment: Yep, not trying to tell you not to use lodash if you want to! I just personally find seeing the two side by side to be helpful for context so I figured someone else might also.